Generic PostitiveNumber struct in C#
I am trying to create a concept of positive numbers only, using the record struct and the INumber<T> interface. I expected this to work:
public record struct PositiveNumber<T>(T Value) where T : INumber<T>
{
    public T Value { get; init; } = Value >= 0 ? Value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Value));
}

This causes a compile error on Value >= 0 saying that

Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'.

I thought constraining the generic to INumber<T> solves this. Is this not possible, or am I doing something wrong here?

You can use INumberBase<TSelf>.Zero:
public record struct PositiveNumber<T>(T Value) where T : INumber<T>
{
    public T Value { get; init; } = Value >= T.Zero ? Value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(Value));
}

Also might be useful:

How to generate constant values with generic math
Generic math how to cast from INumber to a "concrete" type (int/double/etc)


Both @Ortund's and this solution work, but this is more descriptive, so I'm marking it as accepted.

Unfortunately, C# doesn't support using comparison operators directly on generic type parameters constrained to interfaces.
You'll need some additional constraints but I'm lazy so I find helper methods easier:
using System;
using System.Numerics;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var positiveInt = new PositiveNumber<int>(5);
        var positiveDbl = new PositiveNumber<double>(3.14);
        
        var invalidNumber = new PositiveNumber<int>(-549); // Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    }
}

public record struct PositiveNumber<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    public PositiveNumber(T value)
    {
        Value = value >= default(T) ? value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
    }

    public T Value { get; init; }
}

Hope this helps.

"You'll need some additional constraints" - actually no additional constraints are needed, T.Zero can be used for comparison here.
